# Updating SQL tables in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, updating

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myDB_UpdateThreadComments]
    @ID bigint, 
    @HasBeenChecked Char,
    @View Char
AS
    /***** Make the thread not view'able, but checked *****/
    UPDATE myDB_Posts
    SET [HasBeenChecked] = 'True',
        [View] = 'False'
    WHERE [ID] = @ID

    /***** Make the thread's comments all view'able, but checked *****/
    UPDATE myDB_Comments
    SET [HasBeenChecked] = 'True',
        [View] = 'True'
    WHERE [ID] = @ID
```

In the stored procedure, I am updating 2 tables. Table number one is a forum thread. Table two is the thread's comments. The thread ID is the same for both. Will I run into any unforeseen errors because they share the same ID? The 2 tables also share 2 view similar columns.

The code works, and I am about to go live with it. Just wanted to gets other eyes on it.

Comment: The sql looks good to me - the underlying table design also looks reasonable. For sure can 2 tables share the same ID - but in your description you didn't clarify if the ID is used either as a primary key or as a foreign key (I assume in the Posts table it is a primary key and in the comment table it is a foreign key). When the ID is used as a primary key, there is generally also a unique constraint on it.. This way your update will always affect only one row. If the ID is not unique, the update can affect more than one row. (e.g. which can happen for foreign keys).

Comment: Thanks Andreas. The ID for Table1 is unique as guessed, and the same ID for Table2 is just a column. The code works as a way to reject a thread and to approve all comments. There was a glitch where approving a thread also approved all comments for it. I simply made a separate stored procedure for approving.